# Permission problem with cp/mv and nfs

Tags: permissions, nfs, ntfs

I have a drive with ntfs mounted on one computer and made available to a second computer using NFS. On the second computer I'm able to read and write to this drive but with a catch; cp will create a file but get:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘wgb/ccc’: Operation not permitted
```

first time and then called second time will succeed writing contents (when file already exist)

mv will always fail with:

```
mv: cannot create regular file ‘wgb/ccc’: Operation not permitted
```

How to diagnose/fix it?

---

The setup is

Comp1 (ubuntu server)  /etc/fstab

```
UUID=01CF340CBDFC8A90 /mnt/wgb  ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0
```

Comp1 /etc/exports

```
/mnt/wgb *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Comp2 (Linux Mint) /etc/fstab

```
192.168.0.4:/mnt/wgb    /mnt/wgb    nfs auto,nofail,noac    0   0
```

Comment: easiest solution would be for comp1 to nfs-mount 192.168.0.4:/mnt/wgb. While in theory (nt)mount on (nfs)mount  on (device)mount might work, in practice they seldom.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm able to follow you. The device is physically connected to Comp1 (external drive on usb cable) and is formatted under ntfs. In my understanding the Comp1 have to mount the device directly - otherwise nobody will have any access to it. Am I wrong? With this in mind what changes do you suggest?

Comment: Apologies I read 'SMB' instead of 'NT' ...

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory vs the file.  `ls -ld dirname`
If the directory is not writable, you can overwrite a file which is writable by you because that doesn't change the directory itself.  mv which calls the rename system call, needs write permissions to the directory.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work by changing

```
no_root_squash
```

to

```
all_squash,anongid=0,anonuid=0
```